# Como puedo obtener un valor después de una petición $HTTP en AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estoy intentando hacer un `console.log()` de un `array` que lleno cuando hago la petición `http` pero imprime vació, es posible hacer que ejecute primero toda la función del `http`  `$scope.users();` y luego salga en la consola el resultado.
**PD**: El `console.log` lo puedo hacer dentro de la petición `http` pero no es lo que deseo, hay alguna otra forma, promesas o algo parecido?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter) {

    $scope.users = function() {
        $scope.arrItem = [];
        $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(function(res) {
            $scope.users = res.data;
            $filter('filter')($scope.users, function(value, index, array){
                if (value.userId == 1) {
                    $scope.arrItem.push(value);
                };                
            } , true);
        });
    }

    $scope.test = function() {
        $scope.users();
        console.log($scope.arrItem);

    }
    $scope.test();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="user in arrItem">
            {{ user }}
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: He logrado después de ciertos días de investigación y ayudas, una solución que puede servir para las diferentes personas que pertenecemos a la comunidad, edito mi pregunta con la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para el problema que tenia, tuve que usar el servicio de `angularJs` llamado [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) para manejar las promesas y era justo lo que andaba buscando, existen varias maneras de hacer promesas...
 En la función `$scope.users();` hacemos uso del servicio `$q` como se puede ver a continuación:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter, $q) {

    $scope.users = function() {
        return $q(function(resolve,reject) {
            $scope.arrItem = [];
            $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(function(res) {
                $scope.users = res.data;
                $filter('filter')($scope.users, function(value, index, array){
                    if (value.userId == 1) {
                        $scope.arrItem.push(value);
                    };                
                } , true);
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }

    $scope.test = function() {
        $scope.users().then(function(){
            console.log($scope.arrItem);    
        });     
    }
    $scope.test();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="user in arrItem">
            {{ user }}
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente he programado muy poquito con Angular JS, pero la solución que te planteo es la siguiente.

Como tu has dicho hacerlo con promesas y no avanzar hasta no tener los datos.

Aquí el ejemplo.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter) {

    $scope.users = async function() {
        $scope.arrItem;
        //Nos guardamos la respuesta 
        let response = await $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
        //Recogemos nuestros datos

        let data = await response.data

        //Asignamos
        $scope.arrItem = data

    }

    $scope.test = async function() {
      //Esperamos hasta que acabe
      await $scope.users();

      //Mostramos los datos
      for(let a of  $scope.arrItem) {
        console.log(a.title)
      }

    }
    $scope.test();

});
```

Aquí por si quieres probarlo -> [Link](https://jsbin.com/hikogacoqi/edit?js,console)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu solución planteada, pero necesito una solución con la estructura de mi pregunta.

Comment: de hecho el then es una espera de la promesa

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo conmigo, pero  para mi personalmente es más claro y más lipio el codigo aparte de que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

primero que todo, te recomiendo separar el controlador de los servicios, para que tengas mejor organizado el código y puedas reutilizarlo.
En este caso puedes colocar el controlador algo así

```
 app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','$state','myCtrlService',
    function($scope,$state,myCtrlService) {

        $scope.users = function(){
            url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
            //si quieres enviar data 
            var data = {};
            //haces una promesa
            myCtrlService.myCtrlService(data,url).then(function(promise){
                //devuele el resultado deseado
                var result = promise.data;
            })
        }

    }]);
```

Ahora creas el archivo services.js, o como quieras llamar al servicio

```
//aquí inyectas el servicio que tiene como nombre myCtrlService
 app.factory('myCtrlService',['$http', function($http){
    //Objeto que te devolera la info del servicio que vas a consumir
    var services = {};

    services.myCtrlService = function(data,URL){
//consume el servicio api rest enviando la data y URL, si no tienes que enviarle data, le envias solo el parametro dela url
        var promise = $http.get(window.urlService + URL,data)
            .success(function(data){
                //devuelve la información del servicio web
                return data;
            })
            .error(function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
        return promise;
    };
    return services;
}]);
```

**Puedes hacerlo tambien en el mismo archivo. Quedaría algo así**

```
$scope.users = function(){
    $scope.arrItem = [];
    serviceMyCtrl().then(function(promise){
        //devuele el resultado deseado
        var result = promise.data;
        console.log(result);
    })
}

serviceMyCtrl = function(){
//consume el servicio api rest enviando la data y URL, si no tienes que enviarle data, le envias solo el parametro dela url
    var promise = $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
        .success(function(data){
            //devuelve la información del servicio web
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    return promise;
};
```

Recuerda que debes añadir el nuevo archivo en el index.

cualquier duda con gusto la atenderé.
Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: No puede ser de otra forma sin tener que crear servicio, se puede hacer con la misma estructura como realice la pregunta?.

Comment: Puedes crear el servicio dentro del mismo archivo. Revisa que actualicé el código. Es la misma estructura. Espero te sirva.